# How do I compare Record Sets or Record Groups in Oracle?

Tags: oracle

I have an assignment where I have two tables. Both of these two tables have multiple records that can be grouped by a certain ID creating record sets within those two tables

Those record sets can have various number of records. The trick is I have to compare those two tables and compare them by those record sets. If one record set ordered by update date (one of the record fields) doesn't find an identical record set in another table, I have to output that record set

What is the best way to do it? How do I compare two different tables by record groups/record sets/record blocks?

Should I use sub-query factoring? Should I temporary tables? Should I use something else?

Thank you very much for your generous responses and please let me know if I made my question unclear

Answer (score 1):

i guess you just need a `minus` query to show the differences.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Toad there is a specific function. Or you can use the minus operator or read this other post [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6829212/compare-two-records-and-show-only-the-difference)